# where are filed flight plans / routing stored? or: where does flightaware get route data?

Tags: flight-planning, flight-path

One of my favorite new distractions is to look at the routing information that flightaware.com makes available.  If we pull this one, for example:  http://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAL98/history/20170123/0635Z/KLAX/YMML we can see the route is described as:

PRCH2 DINTY R576 DIALO R576 DENNS BARKR B474 ADOWA B474 ARTOP B474 SON BODEG 2300S/16000E HARVS SCOTT Y32 CG Q53 ISKIM Q94 CANTY H119 ARBEY

Which I can plug into ForeFlight or other flight planners or whatever.  My question is: where does flightaware get this data?  I have to assume that it's created by some combination of the airline dispatch groups and filed with the FAA, and lives in "some database" that the FAA/ATC uses.  But what mechanism does flightaware.com use to get this information?  And is there a way (preferably programmatically) that I can get access to the routing filed for a particular flight or tail number?

Comment: For an overall introduction of how flight plan data are managed in Europe: [Eurocontrol Flight planning](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/flight-planning) and [Flight data services](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/flight-data-services). This is similar for other flow management agencies.